# Kubuntu Locking up

Tags: kubuntu, crash

I just did a fresh install of Kubuntu 14.10 beta 2, KDE 5 plasma (my boot drive is a samsung 840 solid

state drive - not sure if that will matter)

I will be working in Dolphin file explorer browsing a directory when out of the blue, the machine locks

up, the mouse will move but nothing on the mouse or keyboard will work.  I have to hit the power button

and reboot. This also happens when in systems settings, there, and Dolphin is where this has happened,

may occur elsewhere  - don't know.

When it boots up, the blue "Kubuntu" will come up center screen then one of the issues below will

occur:

1)  starting automatic crash report generation: apport

2)  starting automatic crash report generation: apport
     restoring resolver state ...

3)  starting automatic crash report generation: apport
     restoring resolver state ...
     starting uuid generator uuidd

4)  starting automatic crash report generation: apport
     restoring resolver state ...
     starting uuid generator uuidd
  :tc/rc2.d/S0Z sddm: 4: .: can't open /lib/init/init-d-script
                                                        saned disabled edit /etc/defualt/saned

when 1,2 or 3 happen, I have to hit the power button or unplug the PC
when 4 happens, it does boot up. Number 4 may be due to my newly created sddm.conf file containing:

[Autologin]
User=ajub2
Session=plasma.desktop

Please advise, thanks James.